# Slick Slider.Slick is slow In IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, slick.js

I am using slick slider to load some dynamic score data. The issue I face is after filling the div container am calling the slick container.slick to load it again to work with the dynamic data. It work normally in Chrome and FF. Bur IE-10 and 11 it taking around 10 seconds to do that. Any one experiencing something like this issue?. Any kinda fix ? I can't paste complete code here. But please find the snippet

```
jq.each(data, function (index, value) {
  jq('.shs-foxScrlTkrDv').append(self.getGamesDetails(index, value, true).divs);

});

jq('.shs-foxScrlTkrDv').slick({
  //when centermode = true, then slidesToScroll = 2 (set in slick.js)
  dots: false,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 6,
  slidesToScroll: 6,
  fade: false,
  centerMode: true,
  prevArrow: jq('.lftArrow'),
  nextArrow: jq('.rgtArrow'),
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1276,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 5
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 4
      }
    }
  ]
});//Calling the slick again to work
```

Comment: I think this on of many bugs that IE has, you should fill a bug report. Even if there is a way to fix it.

Comment: Where I can log it?

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/ you can select IE when you create a Report.